# NRPE: check_aacraid - used this?

Tags: centos, nagios

I'm getting the same old `Unable to read output` message from this NRPE test. I can run other tests on this machine and I can `su - nagios -c "&lt;path to check_aacraid&gt;"` when running locally and it works.

Looking at `/var/log/messages` shows that the process is opened and started - it just doesn't seem to give back any message(s) that NRPE can digest.

What else can I use to debug this? I've set `debug = 1` in `nrpe.cfg` and I have nagios set in `sudo` as `NOPASSWD:ALL`. (yes, it's a big security hole.. I'm getting desperate to make this work)

Both systems (nagios server and NRPE client) are CentOS 6.2.

EDIT:
To test from the Nagios server I've been using a cmdline:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H &lt;IP of nrpe machine&gt; -c check_aacraid
```

This works ok if I try `check_users` or `check_total_procs` (defaults that come with NRPE installation). It also works if I rename one of these commands to `stuff` and pass that with the `-c` to `check_nrpe`. This leads me to believe that the issue isn't server-side nagios.

On the client side, the only change I've made to `NRPE.CFG` (outside of testing - see above) is to add a line:

```
command[check_aacraid]=/usr/local/sbin/check-aacraid.py
```

Otherwise everything is default.

I can execute this command when logged in as `nagios` and also via `su - nagios -c "cmd"`.

Comment: Please, post the related configuration from nagios server and nrpe server (defined command on both systems) and how you are executing the command manually. You may be missing some parameter or executing it in a different way.

Comment: edits are inline.

Comment: Why did you do NOPASSWD:ALL in /etc/sudoers?  Does the Python script do a 'sudo'?

Comment: @JeffLeyser - yes. There are more sudos in the script. The script isn't v long so Im nearing the point of ditching it and recoding it. This is annoying.

Comment: When you run the check script from the command line, what output do you get?

Comment: Running from cmd line via root or 'su - nagios -c "cmd"' both show the correct output. Same for logging in as nagios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' turns out to be SELinux. When I 'echo 0 /selinux/enforce' the plugin works. Now to figure out how to work with the system instead of around it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the `PATH` in your interactive shell is nice and long and includes everything that `check_aacraid` needs, but the NRPE `PATH` is short and sweet, and lacks something that you need.  Pick your favourite method for enhancing the `PATH` for `check_aacraid`, and chances are all your problems will go away.

As an aside, the general diagnostic method for NRPE is to `strace -f -s 1024` the PID of the NRPE server, and just watch what happens.  It's usually pretty obvious what's going wrong.

Comment: Paths: I wondering about this. I was hoping to eliminate it by testing via su - nagios -c "cmd".   Also - Im running NRPE in xinetd. Can I use strace for that?

Comment: Your su testing won't work, because it won't necessarily emulate the PATH being used by NRPE.  You can strace any running process with the `-p` option.

Comment: I've been working this avenue. strace gives me a tremendous amount of information to sift through.

Comment: It's usually pretty easy to find the plugin invocation you're looking for with a simple text search, and then since it's a PATH issue you're interested in, take a look for execve calls in that child.

Answer (score 0):

The sudo in the script is probably failing because it's not on a tty when NRPE runs.  Check /etc/sudoers for:

```
Default requiretty
```

And comment it out.

Comment: Did that already. Early on.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have tried this already but I was running into this same issue with another plugin.  The solution on my end was to add this line to the `nrpe.cnf`:

```
command[check_aacraid]=sudo /usr/local/sbin/check-aacraid.py
```

in the `sudoers` file:

```
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/check-aacraid.py
```

In addition to the commenting out of Default `requiretty` that you mentioned was already done.

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: I know it's not advisable but have you tried running just straight up as root instead of having it sudo?